# need help Installing mysql server v5.6

Tags: mysql, installation

Installing my SQL for the first time, MySQL server seems to be missing in recommended windows installer. any download i try activates the default installer and it does not show mysql server.

[image]

if i try to add server dosen't show up.[image]

Now i have downloaded server 5.6 manually but do not have any way to install them.
i tried to install by steps in this website https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-mysql/
but mysqld didn't run properly. it had following error

[image]

Comment: Does this help https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

Comment: @HassanVoyeau yep manually downloaded the server 5.6 x32 zip folder (5.7 is not compatible ), as i have mentioned the sqld.exe gave the above error

Comment: Did you follow this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/windows-install-archive.html

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: @HassanVoyeau server is running now. just x64 x86 compatibility issue. previous version works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems none of 8.0 is compatible with previous versions(x86). I had to install server version 5.7 manually(offline installer) with 6.2 workbench for mysql to run on 32bit pc.

i had to uninstall all cleanly or else the default installer would not provide with new packages that i downloaded.

https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/ - all files are here